# Simple aggregation query in CosmosDB takes much longer than SQL

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Same query runs on the cheapest plan.

- Cosmos DB > 40 sec
- MSSQL < 0.5 sec

I understand a scan must be performed to do the calculation, but the performance gap is huge. Any way to improve it?

```
SELECT MAX(c.DateCreated - c.DateShipped)
FROM c
```

[image]

Comment: There is no way a priori for the database to know which record will have the max difference, and therefore a full table scan seems necessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But the classic SQL is too fast, in comparison.

Comment: Then check the explain plan, and also compare data set size.

Comment: Retrieved document size looks like you are loading 1.8GB of data, and you are scanning across all the partitions (not only a scan but a cross partition scan). Not sure a blind comparison is fair, is your MSSQL database also sharded across multiple partitions and are you cross-querying all of them? Could your query be scoped to a particular Partition Key?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Both are simplest setup for testing, 1 container and 1 table. Yes cross all partitions.  My impression was Cosmos DB can easily handle huge amount of data. Seems can't match some cheap SQL instance for this simple aggregation.

Comment: You can improve it by precomputing the value and adding it as indexed property. Cosmos is almost always a bad solution when a query needs to retrieve all documents and the document load time shows it.